# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'documentumServiceForIDP' is defined

Tags: java, spring, jboss

I have a scenario where we deployed two EAR's on JBoss4.2.3. Each Ear has its own applicationContext defined. But I realized while debugging, one application bean definitions overriding the other.

Here is the server log:

> 

```
09:23:23,962 INFO 
> [XmlWebApplicationContext] Refreshing
> org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@1b4aee4:
> display name [Root
> WebApplicationContext]; startup date
> [Thu Jul 08 09:23:23 MDT 2010]; root
> of context hierarchy 09:23:24,103 INFO
> [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML
> bean definitions from ServletContext
> resource
> [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-idp.xml]
> 09:23:24,166 INFO 
> [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML
> bean definitions from URL
> [jar:file:/C:/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp608645178333044413IDP.ear-contents/IDPEJB.jar!/META-INF/applicationContext.xml]
> 09:23:24,181 INFO 
> [XmlWebApplicationContext] Bean
> factory for application context
> [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@1b4aee4]:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@8478d0
> 09:23:24,384 INFO 
> [DefaultListableBeanFactory]
> Pre-instantiating singletons in
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@8478d0:
> defining beans
> [**powersuiteServiceFactory,url,qname,powersuiteService,IDPDocumentumServiceFactory,documentumServiceForIDP,applicationUserName,IDPApplicationContextProvider,idpdctmfactory,externalService,brokerIp,jmsConnectionFactory,redeliveryPolicy,jmsDestination,IDPjmsTemplate,jmsProducer,jmsListener,transactionManager,IDPJmsContainer**];
> root of factory hierarchy
> 
> [[/SecureClaim]] Initializing Spring
> root WebApplicationContext
> 09:23:45,260 INFO  [ContextLoader]
> Root WebApplicationContext:
> initialization started 09:23:45,275
> INFO  [XmlWebApplicationContext]
> Refreshing
> org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@1fbf66c:
> display name [Root
> WebApplicationContext]; startup date
> [Thu Jul 08 09:23:45 MDT 2010]; root
> of context hierarchy 09:23:45,275 INFO
> [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML
> bean definitions from ServletContext
> resource
> [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
> 09:23:45,291 INFO 
> [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML
> bean definitions from URL
> [jar:file:/C:/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp608645178333044413IDP.ear-contents/IDPEJB.jar!/META-INF/applicationContext.xml]
> 09:23:45,306 INFO 
> [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML
> bean definitions from URL
> [jar:file:/C:/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp7456914759893588436SecureClaim.ear-contents/SipsFacelet.jar!/META-INF/applicationContext.xml]
> 09:23:45,322 INFO 
> [DefaultListableBeanFactory]
> Overriding bean definition for bean
> 'applicationContextProvider':
> replacing [Generic bean: class
> [org.idahosif.sips.common.spring.ApplicationContextProvider];
> scope=singleton; abstract=false;
> lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0;
> dependencyCheck=0;
> autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
> factoryBeanName=null;
> factoryMethodName=null;
> initMethodName=null;
> destroyMethodName=null; defined in
> ServletContext resource
> [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]]
> with [Generic bean: class
> [org.idahosif.sips.common.spring.ApplicationContextProvider];
> scope=singleton; abstract=false;
> lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0;
> dependencyCheck=0;
> autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
> factoryBeanName=null;
> factoryMethodName=null;
> initMethodName=null;
> destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL
> [jar:file:/C:/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp7456914759893588436SecureClaim.ear-contents/SipsFacelet.jar!/META-INF/applicationContext.xml]]
> 09:23:45,322 INFO 
> [XmlBeanDefinitionReader] Loading XML
> bean definitions from URL
> [jar:file:/C:/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp7456914759893588436SecureClaim.ear-contents/SipsMessaging.jar!/META-INF/applicationContext.xml]
> 09:23:45,322 INFO 
> [DefaultListableBeanFactory]
> Overriding bean definition for bean
> 'brokerIp': replacing [Generic bean:
> class
> [org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory];
> scope=singleton; abstract=false;
> lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0;
> dependencyCheck=0;
> autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
> factoryBeanName=null;
> factoryMethodName=null;
> initMethodName=null;
> destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL
> [jar:file:/C:/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp608645178333044413IDP.ear-contents/IDPEJB.jar!/META-INF/applicationContext.xml]]
> with [Generic bean: class
> [org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory];
> scope=singleton; abstract=false;
> lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0;
> dependencyCheck=0;
> autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
> factoryBeanName=null;
> factoryMethodName=null;
> initMethodName=null;
> destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL
> [jar:file:/C:/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp7456914759893588436SecureClaim.ear-contents/SipsMessaging.jar!/META-INF/applicationContext.xml]]
> 09:23:45,322 INFO 
> [DefaultListableBeanFactory]
> Overriding bean definition for bean
> 'redeliveryPolicy': replacing [Generic
> bean: class
> [org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy];
> scope=singleton; abstract=false;
> lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0;
> dependencyCheck=0;
> autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
> factoryBeanName=null;
> factoryMethodName=null;
> initMethodName=null;
> destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL
> [jar:file:/C:/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp608645178333044413IDP.ear-contents/IDPEJB.jar!/META-INF/applicationContext.xml]]
> with [Generic bean: class
> [org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy];
> scope=singleton; abstract=false;
> lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0;
> dependencyCheck=0;
> autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
> factoryBeanName=null;
> factoryMethodName=null;
> initMethodName=null;
> destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL
> [jar:file:/C:/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp7456914759893588436SecureClaim.ear-contents/SipsMessaging.jar!/META-INF/applicationContext.xml]]
> 09:23:45,338 INFO 
> [DefaultListableBeanFactory]
> Overriding bean definition for bean
> 'transactionManager': replacing
> [Generic bean: class
> [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager];
> scope=singleton; abstract=false;
> lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0;
> dependencyCheck=0;
> autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
> factoryBeanName=null;
> factoryMethodName=null;
> initMethodName=null;
> destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL
> [jar:file:/C:/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp608645178333044413IDP.ear-contents/IDPEJB.jar!/META-INF/applicationContext.xml]]
> with [Generic bean: class
> [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager];
> scope=singleton; abstract=false;
> lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0;
> dependencyCheck=0;
> autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
> factoryBeanName=null;
> factoryMethodName=null;
> initMethodName=null;
> destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL
> [jar:file:/C:/jboss-4.2.3.GA/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp7456914759893588436SecureClaim.ear-contents/SipsMessaging.jar!/META-INF/applicationContext.xml]]
> 09:23:45,338 INFO 
> [XmlWebApplicationContext] Bean
> factory for application context
> [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext@1fbf66c]:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1632823
> 09:23:45,494 INFO 
> [DefaultListableBeanFactory]
> Pre-instantiating singletons in
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1632823:
> defining beans
> [**powersuiteServiceFactory,url,qname,powersuiteService,documentumServiceFactory,documentumRepository,applicationContextProvider,brokerIp,jmsConnectionFactory,redeliveryPolicy,jmsDestination,IDPjmsTemplate,jmsProducer,jmsListener,transactionManager,IDPJmsContainer,externalServiceFactory,configProperties,externalServiceForIndex,appExternalVarForCAP,processVariables,connectionFactory,destination,jmsTemplate,jmsSender,messageListener,jmsContainer**];
> root of factory hierarchy**
```

I struggling on this for couple of days but I haven't find solution. Please help me if anyone gone through this issue before.

Comment: I don't see what the subject line has to do with the question

Comment: Do you have your applicationContext.xml files stored in any Jar?

Answer (score 1):

> But I realized while debugging, one application bean definitions overriding the other.

Not sure what you saw while debugging, but based on the logs you have provided, you have two separate BeanFactories:

- DefaultListableBeanFactory@8478d0 which combines bean definitions from

  - /WEB-INF/applicationContext-idp.xml
  - IDPEJB.jar!/META-INF/applicationContext.xml
- DefaultListableBeanFactory@1632823 which combines bean definitions from

  - /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
  - IDP.ear/IDPEJB.jar!/META-INF/applicationContext.xml
  - SecureClaim.ear/SipsFacelet.jar!/META-INF/applicationContext.xml

I assume you have two web apps (one in each ear) and they both setup application context.

Your problems seems to be connected to the second context:

- `ApplicationContextProvider` (bean name `applicationContextProvider`) defined in both: `SecureClaim.ear/SipsFacelet.jar!/META-INF/applicationContext.xml` and `/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`
- `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` (bean name `brokerIp`) defined in both: `IDP.ear/IDPEJB.jar!/META-INF/applicationContext.xml` and `SecureClaim.ear/SipsMessaging.jar!/META-INF/applicationContext.xml`
- `RedeliveryPolicy` (bean name `RedeliveryPolicy`) defined in both:  `IDP.ear/IDPEJB.jar!/META-INF/applicationContext.xml` and `SecureClaim.ear/SipsMessaging.jar!/META-INF/applicationContext.xml`
- `JtaTransactionManager` (bean name `transactionManager`) defined in both:
- `RedeliveryPolicy` (bean name `RedeliveryPolicy`) defined in both:  `IDP.ear/IDPEJB.jar!/META-INF/applicationContext.xml` and `SecureClaim.ear/SipsMessaging.jar!/META-INF/applicationContext.xml`

You have to make sure you need to include all this applicationContext.xml files. If that is the case (which I really doubt, but still) you should give your beans different names.

To understand better what is going on, can you post your web.xml for both web apps here?